# expected error not working using angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

i tried to generate the expected errors, so i created a delete function, use api and jsonplaceholder, which contains 100 posts, so i tried to delete posts whose id = 123 means that does not exist in the posts list from jsonplaceholder, I pass in the function to delete posts 123, when I click on button delete the post delete without generating an error message "the post that wants to delete does not exist".

**posts.component.ts**

```
deletePost(post:any){
      this.postService.deletePost(123)
         .subscribe((response:any) => {
           let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
           this.posts.splice(index, 1);
         }, (error:Response) => {
           if(error.status === 404){
              alert("the post that wants to delete does not exist")
           }else{
            alert('error inattendue');
                 console.log(error)
           }  
        });
  }
```

**posts.service.ts**

```
private url:any = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';



deletePost(post:any){
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + post.id)
  }
```

Comment: before passing the postid to deletepost you should add some logic if post exists then pass post id something like this if(postid exists) then this.postService.deletePost(123) else throw errormsg

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you deleted it directly. For this reason, I recommend using toPromise instead of the subscribe function.

```
deletePost(post:any){
      this.postService.deletePost(123)
         .toPromise().
         .then((response:any) => {
           let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
           this.posts.splice(index, 1);
         })
         .catch((error:Response) => {
           if(error.status === 404){
              alert("the post that wants to delete does not exist")
           }else{
            alert('error inattendue');
                 console.log(error)
           }  
         })
  }
```